# Update table query having a composite key as primary key

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I have a table with 3 columns:

1. id
2. string1
3. string2

`id` and `string1` together form a composite primary key

I need to update value of `string2`

```
update tablename 
  set string2="abc" 
where id=1 
  and string1="xyz"
```

Comment: String constants need to be supplied using single quotes in SQL. `"xyz"` refers to a column, `'xyz'` would be a constant  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using single quotes around the string literal values:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET string2 = 'abc'
WHERE id = 1 AND string1 = 'xyz';
```

In most flavors of SQL, double quotes is a means of escaping an identifier (such as a column or table name).

Comment: I cannot assist you beyond the above answer.  If you have another problem, then consider opening a new question.